# strange behavior with images. Wrong image is shown when image is processed

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

This 2 codes don't show the same image:

```
<v:media.image src="uploads/tx_netjapan/{image}" alt="" width="300" />
```

and

```
<v:media.image src="uploads/tx_myext/{image}" alt="" />
```

First code creates an image in typo3temp:

```
/typo3temp/_processed_/csm_Imagename_1234123123.jpg
```

Second code just shows the image:

```
/uploads/tx_myext/Imagename.jpg
```

The strange thing about this is, this are not the same images. It takes another image for the image that get resized. How is that possible?

---

**Edit:**

Changing the width for 1 pixel shows now the right image:

```
<v:media.image src="uploads/tx_netjapan/{image}" alt="" width="301" />
```

Deleting the image in the `_processed_` folder and recreate it with `width=300` creates again the old wrong image.

---

**Edit 2:**

After cleaning all typo3temp folders and all temp mysql tables it works now. But how could that happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TYPO3 stores some processed data in the database (i.e. in `cache_imagesizes` table) to make re-usage of cropped images faster. If you used before image with the same name , which didn't require cropping it could happen that after replacing old metadata where taken from DB.

In case of any doubts, go to **Install Tool** > **Clean up** section and clear tables that indicates to be responsible for images.

Note that's the safe operation, just on next page view client will need to wait little bit longer for creating new data, anyway it won't disturb generation of the new - valid version of images.

Comment: That is exactly what I did. I just don't know what I should say to my client. Cause I can't say if that happens to go installtool and clean the cache tables ;).